# Switching between two .virmc settings with a command?

Tags: vim

Is there a way to switch between two `.vimrc` settings with a command?

Say I have in my `vimrc:`

```
  * Settings 1
  setlocal formatoptions=1 
  setlocal noexpandtab 
  map j gj 
  map k gk

  * Settings 2
  setlocal formatoptions=2
  map h gj 
  map l gk
```

And I want to be able to change between Settings 1 and 2, say by typing `:S1` or `:S2`

The reason for this is that I want to have settings that I use while **coding** and another set while **writing.**

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create the `:S1` and `:S2` commands using `:h :command`. Type these commands to functions and make sure the settings cancel each other out. For instance...

```
command! S1 call Settings1()
command! S2 call Settings2()

fun! Settings1()
    setlocal formatoptions=1
    setlocal noexpandtab
    silent! unmap <buffer> h
    silent! unmap <buffer> l
    nnoremap j gj
    nnoremap k gk
endfun

fun! Settings2()
    setlocal formatoptions=2
    setlocal expandtab
    silent! unmap <buffer> j
    silent! unmap <buffer> k
    nnoremap h gj
    nnoremap l gk
endfun
```

If you don't want to make the settings cancel out, the simplest solution may be to restart vim with a different configuration file. You could also use `set option!` to toggle options and the `mapclear` commands to clear mappings. However, you'll have to get specific for options like `formatoptions` that can't be toggled. You could reset these to the default with `set option&`.

You can however reset all options to the default with `:set all&`. Using this you could, for instance, have `Settings1()` call `:set all&` and `source $MYVIMRC`. Then `Settings2()` could also call them and then set various options. For example...

```
" tons of settings

command! S1 call Settings1()
command! S2 call Settings2()

fun! Settings1()
    set all&
    mapclear
    source $MYVIMRC
endfun

fun! Settings2()
    set all&
    mapclear
    setlocal formatoptions=2
    setlocal expandtab
    nnoremap h gj
    nnoremap l gk
endfun
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to cancel the functions instead of the individual settings? Because my settings for coding are so much that I'll have to look for each and figure out how to cancel it one by one.

Comment: I don't know of a simple way without restarting vim, but I updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try this out. I wonder what'll happen with the colorscheme, I think it won't change?

Comment: It shouldn't change as `colorscheme` is not an `'option'`.